# Custom sorting based on a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column where I have some values like these, and some blank rows too,

```
Mr. & Mrs. X-Large
Mr. & Mrs. Large
Mr. & Mrs. Small
Mr. & Mrs. X-Large 
Mr. & Mrs. Small
Mr. & Mrs. X-Large
Mr. & Mrs. Large
Mr. & Mrs. X-Large
Mr. & Mrs. Large
Mr. & Mrs. Small
Mr. & Mrs. Medium
Mr. & Mrs. 2XL
Mr. & Mrs. 2XL
Mr. & Mrs. Large
Mr. & Mrs. Medium
Mr. & Mrs. Medium
Mr. & Mrs. Large
```

I want to custom sort the sheet where Small comes first, then Medium, then Large, X-Large and So On. I'm looking for some macro that can be used here. Appreciate your help here. Thank You!

Update 07/07 - So I have tried addressing it using Macro this is what I followed,
1. In my excel, I have 3 sheets, Dashboard, Regular Sample Sheet and an additional hidden sheet - Sheet1 
2. On the hidden sheet (Sheet1), I have created an extra column to assign numeric values to sizes like Mr. & Mrs. Small - 1, Mr. & Mrs. Medium - 2, Mr. & Mrs. Large - 3 etc.
2. Used the following Macro on a form control on dashboard page for sorting

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Call PopulateSheet1
Call Sort
Call PopulateRegularSampleSheet
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The following function copies data from Regular sheet to hidden sheet 1

```
Sub PopulateSheet1()
Worksheets("Regular Sample Sheet").Range("A1:BB10000").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BB10000").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

The following function sorts the data on hidden sheet

```
Sub Sort()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BC10000").Sort 
Key1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BC1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

The following copies data back to regular sheet from Hidden sheet

```
Sub PopulateRegularSampleSheet()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:BB10000").Copy
Worksheets("Regular Sample Sheet").Range("A2:BB10000").PasteSpecial 
(xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

So after the Macro is run, both the sheets 'Regular sheet' and hidden sheet 'Sheet1' remains selected . So my question is how to make them un-selected after macro is run.

Comment: I don't know why you would have to create extra rows.  I suggest you create a single extra column containing the sizes, and do a custom sort on that. If you want to try it using Macros, show us what you have tried.  You can use a similar algorithm in VBA, either sorting a VBA array, or using a temporary or hidden worksheet.

Comment: Use custom sort.

Comment: Thanks @ron Rosenfeld. I meant to say extra column. Yes I did create an extra column and assigned numeric values to sizes. Then created a button enabled macro that sorts using those values. Added extra column on a hidden sheet . Once sorted, I' m copy pasting the sorted  rows to original sheet. The only issue I see the rows remain selected after macro is run. Have tried using application. Cutcopy mode =false but that doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste that code  here  ?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell what you are doing wrong. Perhaps you are using `Select`? Almost never a good idea. In order to help us help you and reproduce your problem, I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I have edited the post. Hope it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As several people have suggested in comments, use a Custom Sort. That is, usually you should not go to a macro if the built-in functionality supports what you want to do.

Here is an image that captures how to specify a custom sort order (rather than alphabetic):

[image]

If you do want to sort via a macro, here is a simple macro I recorded which does the same thing, but in VBA code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1:A4") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "Small,Medium,Large", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A4")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub specialSort()
    Dim rSrc As Range, rScratch As Range, C As Range
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsScratch As Worksheet
    Dim V As Variant

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rSrc = wsSrc.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wsScratch = Worksheets.Add
    Set rScratch = wsScratch.Cells(1, 1)

rSrc.Copy rScratch
Set rScratch = rScratch.CurrentRegion
For Each C In rScratch
    C.Offset(0, 1).Value = Split(C)(UBound(Split(C)))
Next C

Set rScratch = rScratch.CurrentRegion
With wsScratch.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=rScratch.Columns(2), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        CustomOrder:="Small,Medium,Large,X-Large,2XL", _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange rScratch
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply
End With

rScratch.Columns(1).Copy rSrc

wsScratch.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

- We use a temporary sheet which we delete after we're done.
- Copy the source data -- *if there are formulas, you can paste special values*
- Create an extra column for the sizes
- Sort by the sizes column.
- Copy back the first column to the original sheet.
- Delete the scratch sheet